# uninitialized constant RUBY_ENGINE

Tags: ruby, rbenv

I've just installed Ruby 1.9.3-p374 into rbenv and am bundling for an application I am working on.  However, when the bundle gets to `binding_of_caller` I see the following error:

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
extconf.rb:7: uninitialized constant RUBY_ENGINE (NameError)
```

running `echo $RUBY_ENGINE` gives me a blank string.  Manually setting `RUBY_ENGINE` to `ruby` doesn't help either.

How can I get round this problem?

Comment: are you using a non-login shell? maybe shell hooks from `rbenv init` are not getting executed.

Answer (score 2):

`RUBY_ENGINE` and `RUBY_VERSION` are both constance defined by ruby for a running ruby program. They are *not* environment variables available on a plain shell which explains why your `echo` command comes back empty handed.

Also, as evidenced by the stacktrace excerpt, you are **not** using Ruby 1.9.3 but the default Ruby 1.8 on a Mac. As on Ruby 1.8, `RUBY_ENGINE` is not available, you get the error you observe.

And the cause of all of this is probably simply that you haven't switched ti actually use your rbenv installed ruby. For that, you should try something like `rbenv global 1.9.3-p374` on your shell and check that your current ruby is the right one (by checking e.g. `ruby --version`).

Comment: tried `rbenv global` and `ruby --version` is as expected.  Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just check whether it is defined first. Something like this

```
if defined?(RUBY_ENGINE) && RUBY_ENGINE == 'jruby'
```